# du and ls commands reporting wrong directory size

Tags: filesystems, ls, disk-usage, ext4

I'm used to the `du` command. I often use it with `-h` option.
I report the result in a text file which I use to track space consumers.

But I was wondered today to see a directory being reported as using *32 PB* (PetaBytes). That's a lot on a 128 GB disk ....

So, my question is: Is this a bug in `du` command or in the `du -h` flag ?
And what additional check might I conduct on the FS knowing that the `ls` command also reports some abnormal amount :

```
Shell = /bin/bash,
Path =  ~/.../data  > ls -la
total 39582418599960
drwxrwxr-x 2 user user  4096 jan  4 09:49 .
drwxrwxr-x 4 user user  4096 jan  4 09:49 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 11330 jan  4 09:49 Fortress.dat
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user    54 jan  4 09:49 villages.dat
```

If I use other options with the `ls` command, result differs :

```
Shell = /bin/bash
Path =  ~/.../data  > ls -l
total 16
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 11330 jan  4 09:49 Fortress.dat
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user    54 jan  4 09:49 villages.dat
```

If I use `du -a`, I see the problem is on the current directory. That's why a simple `ls -l` doesn't report the problem (it doesn't include the current directory in its report) :

```
Shell = /bin/bash
Path =  ~/.../data  > du -a
12  ./Fortress.dat
4   ./villages.dat
39582418599956  .
```

Here are a few characteristics of my disk :

```
Disque /dev/sda : 128GB
Taille des secteurs (logiques/physiques): 512B/512B
Table de partitions : msdos

Numéro  Début   Fin    Taille  Type      Système de fichiers  Fanions
 1      1049kB  124GB  124GB   primary   ext4                 démarrage
 2      124GB   128GB  4083MB  extended
 5      124GB   128GB  4083MB  logical   linux-swap(v1)
```

Meanwhile, I read about "sparse" files which may change the reported size of the files. What I don't understand here is that the problem seems to be on a directory ... Are there sparse directories ??

Apart from this, there is no problem reproted on my SDD.

Thank for any advice ...
Marc.

Comment: That looks like file system corruption to me; could you `sudo touch /forcefsck` and reboot to make sure? This will force a `fsck` of your file systems...

Comment: Bingo ! This is it !
But where do I find the error message of fsck ?
I looked at dmesg but didn't find anything convincing ...
And in /var/log/fsck, the files are empty.

Comment: While it's checking file systems, `fsck` doesn't really have anywhere to log messages; all you can do is read them as they are printed on screen. I'll add my comment above as a proper answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Stephen.
Yes, it is obvious, nowhere to log during fsck as filesystem is not mounted.
My Xubuntu just showed me a splashscreen during the fsck process.
And I didn't get the time to swith to any console to check if something was written.... have a good day.

Answer (score 3):

That looks like file system corruption to me; to fix it, do

```
sudo touch /forcefsck
```

and reboot. This will force a fsck of your file systems.